# Finding disconnected subgraphs in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am working on a Prolog program that takes an NxN matrix that has two random end nodes (and some other constraints) and connects the two nodes. The final constraint is making sure the given solution only contains one connected subgraph. One idea I have for this is to look for one of the end nodes, mark the node as visited. Then, I keep searching for solution nodes adjacent to visited nodes and marking them as visited. When I visit the final end node, I can search the whole matrix for unvisited solution nodes. If there are none then the solution passes.

I believe this is a very expensive solution because I would have to (basically) search through the entire matrix once for every solution node. Also, I would have to keep track of 3 rows of the matrix, the current one, the one above, and the one below, to be able to see if there are any adjacent solution nodes to the visited node.

Are there any more efficient/easier to implement solutions that I'm not thinking of?

Comment: this whole thing depends on your representation of the data involved. please include it. i.e. how do you represent your graph, and matrix, and "solutions" -- what are those? what are "solution nodes"? include simple example data as well for clarty.

Comment: it's a list of lists where 1s indicate an end node, 2s represent a path to connect the 1s.

Comment: show it in the question. it is unclear otherwise.

Comment: If you graph is acyclic then see [top_sort/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=top_sort/2)